# Random Object selected from list but when compared to user input only the first item on list is accepted

Tags: c#, list, winforms, object

My program selects an object(ion) from a list of objects(ions) at random and allows the user to input what they believe to be the values of charge and polarity, however when I check the input against the values of the random object(ion) only the first object on the list is accepted instead of the actual variables. I checked to make sure that the variables are changing, and even when matching it will only accept the charge and polarity of the first ion in the list.

```
this is the list of objects, ion guesser is declared outside
   int IonGuesser;
   public class Ion
    {
        public string Charge; // 1-3 no need to make int as no maths are performed
        public string Polarity; // + or -
        public string Name; // Self explanatory
        public string Formula; // chemical formula eg OH
    }

    List<Ion> Ions = new List<Ion>
    {
        new Ion {Charge = ("1"), Polarity =("-"),Name = ("Hydroxide"), Formula = ("OH")},
        new Ion {Charge = ("1"), Polarity =("+"),Name = ("Hydron"), Formula = ("H")},
        new Ion {Charge = ("1"), Polarity =("+"),Name = ("Lithium"), Formula = ("Li")},
        new Ion {Charge = ("1"), Polarity =("+"),Name = ("Sodium"), Formula = ("Na")},
```

this button click pulls a random ion and displays the formula for the user

```
 private void NextIonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int IonGuesser = rnd.Next(Ions.Count);
        var RandomIon = Ions[IonGuesser];
        IonNameDisplay.Text = RandomIon.Formula;
    }
```

below is the button that is supposed to check if it is correct or not, it will only say that charge("1") and polarity ("-") is correct even when that is not the case

```
    private void IonSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int CorrectCounter = 0;
        var RandomIon = Ions[IonGuesser];
        if (ChargeDropDown.Text == RandomIon.Charge)
        {
            CorrectCounter++;
        }
        if (PolarityDropDown.Text == RandomIon.Polarity)
        {
            CorrectCounter++;
        }
        if (CorrectCounter == 2)
        {
            IonGuessStatus.Text = ("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            IonGuessStatus.Text = ("Incorrect");
        }
```

So when say the ion formula dispalyed is Li, IonGuessStatus should be ("correct") when the input in the dropdown boxes is (1) and (+) however it only says correct when the input is (1) and (-)

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using `IonGuesser` inside `IonSubmitButton_Click` and it'll always be `0` due to you're are declaring a local `IonGuesser` inside `NextIonButton_Click`. BTW, you can shorten your code by just asking `ChargeDropDown.Text == RandomIon.Charge && PolarityDropDown.Text == RandomIon.Polarity`.

Comment: Ion guesser is declared outside of both of these button clicks will it still be local inside them?, also thanks for the && tip

Comment: You need to transform the line `int IonGuesser = rnd.Next(Ions.Count);` in `NextIonButton_Click` into `IonGuesser = rnd.Next(Ions.Count);` otherwise what you're doing is hiding the outter `IonGuesser` (which will remain the same, `0`).

Comment: That worked, you're a legend thanks

Answer (score 0):

removing the int from Int Ionguesser = rnd.Next(Ions.Count);